# Stress test on Django makes it slow while there are free system resources

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache

Today I was doing a stress test to a new Django (1.5.4) running on an Ubuntu Server 12.04 site before going into production and I've found some unexpected results:

Doing 50 requests per second, htop showed a CPU usage of ~50% and RAM also ~50%. I'm not currently using Django cache and doing a normal browser request while doing the stress test it took ~30s to load each page (without any load it takes <= 2s). The server didn't crash during the test, but I dont understad why if there are almost 50% of the resources free it lasts so much... I expected to see a higher CPU and memory usage!

So, my question is: Is there any Django default setting that limits the number of requests per second? Or does Apache or mod_wsgi have any kind of limit? Do I have to change some MySQL config?

(Note: I'm a software engineer, not sysadmin).

Comment: What's going on in the request?  Calls to a database will take some time, but not show up in CPU/RAM/Load

Comment: Yes, the requests are accessing the database everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many workers of django you are running? Maybe server can't load to 100% because you are running small amount of workers, but there are many database connections, so most of the time workers are waiting database, and blocking new connections.

Comment: By default, Apache mod_wsgi works with 1 process and 1 thread, so all requests are enqueued. I changed the configuration and set `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive to work with `processes=2 threads=15` and now all server resources are used when needed. E.g. when robots go through the website and do more than 20 req/s, CPU is now being used at almost 100% capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Probably caching is your answer. I don't know how Django runs on Apache as I run a Gunicorn setup but it makes round trips for every database call.

If you institute some memcache to handle common result sets you should see a large improvement so you don't have to make trips for each request.

Also, 50 concurrent connection requests at a time seems like a lot. Try to tone it down to 5 or 10 then 25 instead of starting at 50.

Just my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I know that using cache would improve the results and I know that doing 50 requests/s is an insane number. I was just testing how much load the server could manage. If I use lower requests/s the performance improves a lot. I just wanted to know why does it last so much if there are idle resources...

Comment: Database round trips are expensive. Especially '50' of them at a time. The idle resources are automatically all taken up at once. If you say, instead of bombarding it 50 at a time spread it out.. like one two requests per second for 25 seconds might give you a better idea of 'constant' traffic @ a high load.

Comment: OK, I'll tell the server admin to do the new test with 1 and 2 requests/s during 1 minute each one and I'll post the results here. Thanks for your tips :) What I don't understand is what you mean with "The idle resources are automatically all taken up at once."

Comment: I've just accepted @VitalBelikov's answer and added an explanation comment. However, thanks for your answer as well! :)